# Why are resistors necessary in the following circuit?

Tags: mosfet, resistors, esp8266

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWmX64.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The circuit is taken from the schematic of a SONOFF of the ITEAD house.

If a gate of a MOSFET behaves like an open circuit, why are resistors needed?

Applying 3.3V from GPIO12 directly to the gate of the MOSFET should work correctly and barely circulate current through the gate of the MOSFET.

Comment: What happens if the GPIO isnt connected to anything? What will be the voltage level at the gate of the mosfet? If the GPIO comes from a microcontroller, there will be times when it acts like an open circuit (i.e. is basically not connected to anything)

Comment: I think by "door" you mean "gate"?

Comment: Sorry for my English, I meant gate

Comment: BEB00 >> What happens if the GPIO isnt connected to anything?

GPIO belongs to an ESP8266, if I connect the gpio directly to the gate of the mosfet, with zero volts in gpio the relay does not activate but with 3.3 if it does, thanks

Comment: The 1k resistor is completely unnecessary for a MOSFET. Somebody took the circuit for a BJT and simply changed it to a MOSFET without bothering to update the rest of the circuit.

Answer (score 2):

R2 is necessary to make sure that the mosfet M1 is in cutoff even if nothing is driving the GPIO12 line. This is important during power-up, for example, at which time the MCU in this system may not be driving GPIO12. If this resistor were absent, the mosfet might turn on during startup and engage the relay erroneously.

R1 is not necessary because M1 is a FET. Were M1 a BJT and not a MOSFET, then this resistor would limit the current into the base. With a BJT, this would be necessary since the base-emitter junction of a BJT basically looks like a diode to the circuit which drives it. R1 is not necessary with a FET but does have the effect of increasing the turn-on/off time of the FET due to the increased RC delay imposed by the 1kOhm resistor and the capacitance of the FET's base input. Of course, this additional RC delay has no effect on the relay since the time for the relay to open and close is so much longer, but it would be more significant if the MOSFET were driving other electronics, rather than a relay.

Comment: Thank you very much for this excellent answer

Comment: Could you give a small example of how R2 can prevent an activation during power-up?

Comment: *Technically* it is often good practice to include R1, since it limits the current flow into the mosfet gate. This can be important because too much current flowing can cause EMI, and also damage the GPIO (although it probably wouldn't in this case)

Comment: @BeB00 indeed. Also because the gate can be quite capacative, there can be stability issues when driving it driectly from a CMOS output which tries to go from 0 to 3.3V in a very short time. Without the resistor the instantaneous current can be surprisingly large. R1 limits it to 3.3mA which will never be a problem.

Comment: It is a voltage divider. the goal of those resistor is to establish the voltage at the gate which will be a ratio of the resistors

Answer (score 0):

These resistors work as a voltage divider. The voltage applied to the MOSFET will be a ratio according to the following formula:

Vgate = VGPIO12 * (R2/(R1+R2))

When the voltage is 3.3V that would mean 3 V will arrive at the MOSFET.

They are not pull-up/pull-down resistors.

Comment: R2 also functions as a pull-down resistor, however, and it's quite essential that it do so.

Comment: The MOSFET gate will still get .909 of whatever floating voltage will be. Although It may be enough to not activate the MOSFET, it cannot be consider a pull-down. Because adjusting that resistor will affect the circuit in a different ways other than just adjusting a pull-down.

Comment: But the floating voltage will *also* get discharged to ground through the combination of R1 and R2. It *is* a pull-down resistor in addition to its other functions.

Comment: So, you are saying it is a 11K pull down, once both resistors are in series? So, you are saying that those 2 resistors can be replaced by a 11K resistor? I will have to disagree with you. The fact that a resistor is connected to ground does not make it a pull down. If that is the case, all R2 in a voltage divider are also pull down. Which is inaccurate once there are different formulas to model each of them. A pull down resistor will drive the signal by its own. In the case here what is driven the signal at the gate is the voltage left after applying the voltage divider formula.

Comment: I'm not saying that you can replace them with a single resistor. It's a voltage divider, after all, and those require two resistors. I am saying that *one of the functions of the resistor here*, regardless of whether it was designed that way or not, is to pull the gate to ground when the gate drive signal goes high-impedance. I get the impression you don't fully understand what the function of a pull-down resistor is, or how floating gates behave, given your words above. Don't blindly apply formulas, try to understand the physics and you'll see.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. But, the function of that resistor is not a pull down. Physics will tell that whatever voltage applied to a circuit, current will flow in the easiest path it finds. If you have a circuit with a LED and a resistor connect to the LED and ground, that resistor will have current flowing to it and that will not make it a pull down. Pull down is a concept. When you get a circuit, you use formulas to model. One of the answers is telling R1 could be removed. That is what happens when you mistake the concepts. You dont fully understand the circuit and make mistakes

Comment: R1 *could* be removed, though. It's not performing any useful function in this circuit--3.3 volts is already way too low to properly drive an IRF530, dividing it to a lower voltage certainly won't help. R2 is, however, a pull-down resistor *because it pulls the gate low*. I didn't say anything about current flowing through it--a pulldown resistor is one in parallel to a high-impedance input, *which includes the gate of a FET*. I also would like to note that "current will flow in the easiest path" is a major misconception, current flows in *all* paths, inversely proportional to resistance.

Comment: https://youtu.be/FrpYtBeKzKk this is using a IRF520. It is a different Mosfet but with similar specifications. It also does not have the voltage divider but it is driven by a 3.3 voltage pin. These mosfets have a gray area between 2.5 and 3.6 and it will depend on the circuit to operate.

Comment: I think you're making the common mistake of thinking that threshold voltage is the point at which a FET turns fully on. It is not, it's the point where it just begins to conduct. You need to drive the gate a few volts higher than the threshold voltage in order to drive it fully on. If you're lucky, you might find an IRF530 that has a threshold voltage of just 2 volts, and 3.3 might be enough to turn it partially on, but the 530 is designed to be driven with 10 volts and you can't rely on it working at less than half that.

Comment: You are right. But you dont need a Mosfet fully on to drive a device. It depends on what is required by that device. Maybe a different Mosfet could be used and for that, a voltage divider would not be needed. But, I insist. In that circuit presented in the question, those 2 resistors are voltage dividers. Whether that is required by the whole circuit or not, is another question and we need more datasheets to conclude it

Comment: Taking R1 off or varying R2 without considering R1 would affect the circuit in different ways as opposed as what would happen if it was a pull down

Comment: 3.3 volts is by no means adequate to turn on a FET with a maximum threshold voltage of 4 volts though. And please, try to understand that a resistor can be more than one thing at once! This resistor is both a pull-down *and* part of a voltage divider.